# Is it advised against to store a large STL object into std::unordered_map as value?

Tags: c++, stl, hashtable, unordered-map, trie

For example, consider the following trie implementation.

```
struct Trie: unordered_map<char, pair<bool, Trie> >
```

Should a pointer to the `struct Trie` be stored instead?

```
struct Trie: unordered_map<char, pair<bool, Trie *> >
```

Since a `struct Trie` object can get quite large, will the first implementation be less efficient as the trie grows large?

Here, managing the internal memory alloc & dealloc of the `Trie` shouldn't be too much of a hassle, so not considering the trouble of manually `new / delete`, which implementation should be preferred?

Comment: How can one answer this without considering the *"trouble of manually `new`/`delete`"*? In my experience this is a major concern causing all kinds of ripple effects through the API.

Comment: But which method should be preferred, in terms of pure efficiency?

Comment: Publicly inheriting from standard containers is potentially asking for undefined behavior in the future.

Comment: Of course, a trie isn't a hash table....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Since you apparently have enough of C++11 available to use `std::unordered_map`, you should strongly avoid owning raw pointers. Instead of `pair<bool, Trie*>`, use `pair<bool, unique_ptr<Trie>>`.
2. You simply cannot use the first approach, as `std::pair` (and all standard library containers) requires its template arguments to be complete types, which is not true in your case - `Trie` is not completely defined yet.
3. It's generally a bad idea to publically inherit from standard library containers; they are not designed for it and have no virtual interface. Prefer composition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain a bit more about the third point? What do you mean by "prefer composition" in this context?

Comment: @lwxted I meant you should store the map in the `Trie`, and not inherit from it. Of course, it depends on your particular use case.